# dynamically created datagridview columns not accessible unless added to a form...why?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

We simply created a DataGridView control dynamically and bound it to a DataTable. We were tying to style certain columns. But, when we tried to access the columns we got a null reference. On further investigation we found that if we add the DataGridView control to the main form, and then try to access its columns, it works fine!!!

Code which throws error:

```
DataGridView gv = new DataGridView();
gv.DataSource = GetDataTable(); //binding it to datatable
Debug.Assert(gv.Columns == null);
```

Code which works fine:

```
DataGridView gv = new DataGridView();
gv.DataSource = GetDataTable(); //binding it to datatable
this.Controls.Add(gv); //adding to form
Debug.Assert(gv.Columns == null); //the assertion fails!
```

Why is this behaviour so? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you need a workaround? What are you doing with the DGV if you're not adding it to a form?

Comment: the creation of the gridview control happens in a thread. we were hoping to "finish" all the work here...before we went back to the main thread. Plus in the main thread we don't have a reference to the dynamically created control. We'd have to go in for a major re-write...which is why I asked if there was a workaround

Comment: Beats me why one would want to create a dgv in a separate thread. After all, it's getting the data and filling the grid what's time consuming, not the grid creation.

Comment: i don't disagree...we've mixed a lot of code...big mess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem but I am not sure it could help you.

You can attach an handler to `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event.

When the `DataGridView` is shown in the main thread if would rise that event and there you have all columns created and accessible

Comment: Yes, its amazing how I missed this out...! :)

Answer (score 0):

Er, wee bit of a stab in the dark; but its likely because the columns generated by use of the  `AutoGenerateColumns` property require a `BindingContext` to properly generate and manage the bindings for the cell values. Typically, that BindingContext wouldn't be able to be determined until the Parent control is set.

Comment: PS. What's wrong with adding it as a child control? What else do you want to use it for?